# Full Rank Matrix with a specific construction

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Assume that we have a $p \times p$  matrix $Z$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2^p}$

$$Z=\begin{bmatrix}
w_1 & w_1^2& w_1^4& ...   & {w_1}^{2^{\frac{p}{2}-1}}  &  \alpha_1w_1 &  \alpha_1w_1^2&  \alpha_1w_2^4&   ...   &  \alpha_1{w_1}^{2^{\frac{p}{2}-1}}\\
w_2 & w_2^2&w_2^4&  ...   & {w_2}^{2^{\frac{p}{2}-1}}  &  \alpha_2w_2 &  \alpha_2w_2^2&\alpha_2w_2^4&     ...   &  \alpha_2{w_2}^{2^{\frac{p}{2}-1}}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots&\vdots& \vdots \\
w_p & w_p^2&w_p^4&  ...   & {w_p}^{2^{\frac{p}{2}-1}}  &  \alpha_pw_p &  \alpha_pw_p^2& \alpha_pw_p^4&    ...   &  \alpha_p{w_p}^{2^{\frac{p}{2}-1}}\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
where $w_i \in \mathbb{F}_{2^p}$ and $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}_{2^p}$ and $\forall \alpha_i$ is different from each other. How can I satisfy (which conditions are necessary) that this matrix has full rank?

P.S. This matrix construction is similar to the Moore matrix except half of the columns of $Z$ matrix is multiplied with $\alpha_i$s.

Thanks in advance.

Elif

Comment: Well, it's rather of size $(2p)\times p$.

Comment: It has $p$ rows, and either $2p$ or $2^p$ columns, depending on what's in the dots.

Comment: I have just edited, it should be $p \times p$